# Using Abbreviations In The Questions

Tags: discussion

Is it disrespectful to use abbreviations like sth to ask questions on this site?

Comment: 'Disrespectful' is not the first word I would think of. 'Very annoying' and 'imposing a lot of effort on many readers' and 'saving time at the expense of others who would normally want to help you' would come first. But yeah, then maybe 'disrespectful' and 'rude' and 'lazy' and 'sloppy' would come up. You're spending a few moments to ask a question, why not try to make it look reasonable? Possible answerers (should) have no difficulty with unintentionally errors from non-native speakers, but intentionally making things difficult to read is awful.